# IOS NSMutableAttributedString crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a problem that I hope that you can help me.

I use `NSMutatableAttributedString` to load html in `UILabel` but all time the application crash on

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    self.attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
});
```

I tried to add `dispatch_async` but nothing changed.

So Please help me,

Comment: Disregard that answer I was incorrect you can for objects. Like I said I don't use much

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a property in a block. It can be assigned in the block, but when the block leaves the heap or stack so does the pointer.

unless you do __block before the property goes into the block

I know like if I want to access a bool inside a block and keep the value when i exit I would do something like

```
__block BOOL myBool = NO;
```

then in my block I could set it
    ^{
       myBool = YES;
    }

```
//myBool is YES now!
```

here give this a once over

[a link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: Please can you more explain ?

Comment: yeah give me a few minutes I'll have to look up exactly how to do it. I don't usually mess with blocks much

Comment: something like that I'll have to look it up, but the underbar underbar block tell the compiler you'll want the value back after the block exits